# Change javascript before its executed

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, firefox

I want to open a website, change its javascript, then show the website + execute my changed js.

1) Is this possible?

2) How is this possible? ( VB.net, C#, FF + Addons )

Thx in advance

EDIT: To your better understanding, I just want the js to be just changed for my browser output!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Greasemonkey. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Also see Same Origin Policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: tried it already. i removed some js from a site with greasemonkey but the js still got executed. I think this is because greasemonkey apply my js code after the originals website code is executed

Comment: @MichaelStark: You can set the execution time of greasemonkey script, by default it's onDOMready.

Comment: you want to change output on the server? Before you send content to client? If so and you are using IIS7+, you can write HTTP module and handle this in PreSendRequestContent event.

Comment: I just looked into it, and it appears Greasemonkey is indeed capable of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This nice software act a http proxy, and provide a script engine that can intercept and transform requests and response. In your case, you can replace on the fly the target javascript content.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it's possible.

2) I don't know how to do it via any of the listed methods, but one method that would work is to download the website's HTML and JavaScript, modify it on your computer, set up a local webserver serving the modified HTML and JavaScript, and (optionally) change your hosts file to indicate that whatever domain you're trying to spoof is located at localhost.  If you want to also interact with the remote server sometimes, you could set up a program on your webserver that responds to a 404 by requesting the page from the remote server (by IP address).  I currently only know how to do this in PHP, however.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that in php?

Comment: In short, you set your webserver (possibly via a .htaccess file) to redirect all requests for missing files to a single index.php, then in that index.php, you use curl to forward the exact same request to the remote server.  When curl returns, you simply send the same HTTP headers to the client, and echo the response body unmodified.  I'd suggest using XAMPP, since that comes with PHP and Apache (the webserver that uses .htaccess files) prepackaged.

Comment: The other methods suggested appear to be much easier, however - this is really just a proof that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Opera's userscripts](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/#loadingscripts). You can execute something like

```
window.opera.addEventListener("BeforeScript", function onchange(e){
    if(! myURIregexp.test(e.element.src))
        return;
    var script = e.element.text;
    /* do something with the script text, for example replacing */
    ev.element.text = script;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fidder2. You can change anything you want to a local file with Fidder [AutoResponder](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp)